# Precedence of operation in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am very new to Ruby, so please accept my apologies if this question is wierd

I tried puts `5-8.abs` which returned `-3`, and then I tried puts `(5-8).abs` which returned `3`.

What is happening exactly when I try puts `5-8.abs`, it seems like `abs` is ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5-8.abs seems to be doing 5-(8.abs) = 5-8 = -3 like you got.

Also, any time precedence is the least bit up in the air, explicit parenthesization helps.

Answer (score 9):

It's a precedence issue. The method call, `.abs`, is evaluated before the minus operator.

```
5-8.abs # => equivalent to 5-(8.abs)
```

Think of it this way - whitespace is not significant in Ruby. What would you expect to happen if you saw this?

```
5 - 8.abs
```

Here's a reference for [Ruby precedence rules](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#expressions).

Comment: Is - an operator? I was under the impression in ruby everything is a method.

Comment: Operators are special. They're evaluated differently (as you can see) and some of them can't be redefined (such as `=` and most of the logical operators). There's some useful stuff if you google "operator method ruby".

Answer (score 4):

Method call (`8.abs` in this case)always has higher Precedence than operators (`-` in this case).

So, `5-8.abs` translats to `5-(8.abs) = 5 - 8 = -3`